# How to sync train and test codebooks in Accord.Net

Tags: c#, tree, random-forest, accord.net

Question: Is there a random forest example that separates between a train and test set? The current example I found in the Accord-Net ML test project uses the very same data for training and testing.

Apparently the issue I am having is that syncing the generated labels (the ints) across the test and train sets. I am generating the train labels as such:

```
int[] trainOutputs = trainCodebook.Translate("Output", trainLabels);

And the test labels similarly:

int[] testOutputs = testCodebook.Translate("Output", testLabels);

Finally I train with the train data and test with the test data:

var forest = teacher.Learn(trainVectors, trainOutputs);

int[] predicted = forest.Decide(testVectors);
```

Unless the first three rows are the same in both the train and test sets the labels are different and it accordingly it produces a very high error rate.

I attempted to simply create my codebook manually with the ternary strings:

```
new Codification("-1","0","1");
```

Unfortunately this produces a runtime error stating that the given key wasn't in the dictionary. I'm sure there is a way to synchronize key generation in two separate codebooks. I'm able to make it work with the code below IF I add three lines of my train data, containing all three keys, to the top of my test data. Not my preferred solution ;=)

Here's the entire test I'm running:

```
 [Test]
 public void test_learn()
 {
 Accord.Math.Random.Generator.Seed = 1;

    /////////// TRAINING SET ///////////
    // First, let's load the TRAINING set into an array of text that we can process
    string[][] text = Resources.train.Split(new[] { "\r\n" },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Apply(x => x.Split(','));

    int length = text[0].Length;
    List<int> columns = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        columns.Add(i);
    }
    double[][] trainVectors = text.GetColumns(columns.ToArray()).To<double[][]>();

    // The first column contains the expected ternary category (i.e. -1, 0, or 1)
    string[] trainLabels = text.GetColumn(0);
    var trainCodebook = new Codification("Output", trainLabels);
    int[] trainOutputs = trainCodebook.Translate("Output", trainLabels);

    ////////// TEST SET ////////////

    text = Resources.test.Split(new[] { "\r\n" },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Apply(x => x.Split(','));

    double[][] testVectors = text.GetColumns(columns.ToArray()).To<double[][]>();
    string[] testLabels = text.GetColumn(0);
    var testCodebook = new Codification("Output", testLabels);
    int[] testOutputs = testCodebook.Translate("Output", testLabels);

    var teacher = new RandomForestLearning()
    {
        NumberOfTrees = 10,
    };

    var forest = teacher.Learn(trainVectors, trainOutputs);
    int[] predicted = forest.Decide(testVectors);

    int lineNum = 1;
    foreach (int prediction in predicted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Prediction " + lineNum + ": " 
        + trainCodebook.Translate("Output", prediction));
        lineNum++;
    }
    // I'm using the test vectors to calculate the error rate
    double error = new ZeroOneLoss(testOutputs).Loss(forest.Decide(testVectors));

    Console.WriteLine("Error term is " + error);

    Assert.IsTrue(error < 0.20); // humble expectations ;-)
}
```

Comment: You should really have **only one** codebook created from the training set, and you should use it to pre-process data from both the training *and* the testing set.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured it out. See the code below:

Okay, I think I was able to fix it. The problem was a faulty implementation of Serialization in DecisionTree. Fortunately we have the code - see the fix below:

```
namespace Accord.MachineLearning.DecisionTrees
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Runtime.Serialization;
  using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
  using System.IO;
  using Accord.Statistics.Filters;
  using Accord.Math;
  using AForge;
  using Accord.Statistics;
  using System.Threading;


/// <summary>
///   Random Forest.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
///   Represents a random forest of <see cref="DecisionTree"/>s. For 
///   sample usage and example of learning, please see the documentation
///   page for <see cref="RandomForestLearning"/>.</para>
/// </remarks>
/// 
/// <seealso cref="DecisionTree"/>
/// <seealso cref="RandomForestLearning"/>
/// 
[Serializable]
public class RandomForest : MulticlassClassifierBase, IParallel
{
    private DecisionTree[] trees;
    **[NonSerialized]
    private ParallelOptions parallelOptions;**


    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets the trees in the random forest.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public DecisionTree[] Trees
    {
        get { return trees; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets the number of classes that can be recognized
    ///   by this random forest.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    [Obsolete("Please use NumberOfOutputs instead.")]
    public int Classes { get { return NumberOfOutputs; } }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Gets or sets the parallelization options for this algorithm.
    /// </summary>
    ///
    **public ParallelOptions ParallelOptions { get { return parallelOptions; } set { parallelOptions = value; } }**

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a cancellation token that can be used
    /// to cancel the algorithm while it is running.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public CancellationToken Token
    {
        get { return ParallelOptions.CancellationToken; }
        set { ParallelOptions.CancellationToken = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Creates a new random forest.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <param name="trees">The number of trees in the forest.</param>
    /// <param name="classes">The number of classes in the classification problem.</param>
    /// 
    public RandomForest(int trees, int classes)
    {
        this.trees = new DecisionTree[trees];
        this.NumberOfOutputs = classes;
        this.ParallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Computes the decision output for a given input vector.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <param name="data">The input vector.</param>
    /// 
    /// <returns>The forest decision for the given vector.</returns>
    /// 
    [Obsolete("Please use Decide() instead.")]
    public int Compute(double[] data)
    {
        return Decide(data);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Computes a class-label decision for a given <paramref name="input" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input">The input vector that should be classified into
    /// one of the <see cref="ITransform.NumberOfOutputs" /> possible classes.</param>
    /// <returns>A class-label that best described <paramref name="input" /> according
    /// to this classifier.</returns>
    public override int Decide(double[] input)
    {
        int[] responses = new int[NumberOfOutputs];
        Parallel.For(0, trees.Length, ParallelOptions, i =>
        {
            int j = trees[i].Decide(input);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref responses[j]);
        });

        return responses.ArgMax();
    }

   [OnDeserializing()]
    internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.ParallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
    }
}
}
```